# Android Declaring Buttons Programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have done tons of searching on the internet tonight and this is what I have come up with. For some reason it is not working. I am not getting any errors and I can verify my loops are actually running. Here is my code.

```
TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablelayout1);
    while (numsounds>0){
        Log.d("MYTAG", ""+numsounds);

        if(numsounds>=3){
            Log.d("MYTAG", ""+numsounds);
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {


            int button_num = j + 1 + ( row_num * 3);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            buttonparams.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
            int btnwidth = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            buttonparams.width = btnwidth;
            buttonparams.weight = .31f;
            Button btn = new Button(this);
            btn.setLongClickable(true);
            btn.setLayoutParams(buttonparams);
            btn.setText(soundtitleArray[button_num]);
            btn.setId(j + 1 + ( button_num));
            btn.getBackground().setAlpha(150);
            btn.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
            btn.setOnLongClickListener(buttonLongClickListener);
            row.addView(btn);

            }
            numsounds=numsounds-3;
            Log.d("MYTAG", ""+numsounds);
            table.addView(row);
            row_num = row_num+1;
        }
        if(numsounds<3){
            Log.d("MYTAG", ""+numsounds);
            TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
            for (int j = 0; j < numsounds; j++) {


                int button_num = j + 1 + ( row_num * numsounds);
                row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                buttonparams.height = LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
                int btnwidth = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 1, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
                buttonparams.width = btnwidth;
                float btnweight = 1/numsounds;
                buttonparams.weight = btnweight;
                Button btn = new Button(this);
                btn.setLongClickable(true);
                btn.setLayoutParams(buttonparams);
                btn.setText(soundtitleArray[button_num]);
                btn.setId(j + 1 + ( button_num));
                btn.getBackground().setAlpha(150);
                btn.setOnClickListener(buttonClickListener);
                btn.setOnLongClickListener(buttonLongClickListener);
                row.addView(btn);

                }
                table.addView(row);
                row_num = row_num+1;
                numsounds=numsounds-1;
                Log.d("MYTAG", ""+numsounds);
        }
    }
```

I know the code is running because it is outputing the change in numbers to logcat. What i can figure out is it keeps giving me a blank screen with only my background showing. The buttons are not showing up.

Also My Imports are as follows.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import com.<MYAPP>.SoundBoard;
import com.<MYAPP>.R;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnLongClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.ads.AdView;
import android.widget.TableRow.LayoutParams;
```

I declared the buttonparams at the beginning of my class as:

```
private TableLayout.LayoutParams buttonparams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();
```

Comment: layout params you've used for the tablerow should be of TableRow.LayoutParams, check the imports, And also for TableLayout also

Comment: ill update my question with the imports. I already have that btw.

Comment: I am not sure but Take a generic type View.LayoutParams instead of specific i.e TableRow.LayoutParams, because You have used the layout params for the Buttons also

Comment: Ill try that right now

Comment: WHat about the value of `btnwidth`, have you checked that? Just to be sure that it's not 0 or so. ;)

Comment: Yes i have checked that it is equal to 1dip in px. I have done this before statically and im trying to recreate it dynamically

Comment: Ok I have tried with it as import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;  and still no dice.

Comment: A width of 1dip will probably lead to the button being invisible, because it's simply not wide enough.

Comment: It worked statically because it automatically widens to the text because of the weight being set. but just for fun i just tried with it set to be 300px as im using a tablet for testing. And still nothing is showing up

Comment: @Pragnani I didnt understand what you were saying at first. But you were correct I changed private TableLayout.LayoutParams buttonparams = new TableLayout.LayoutParams();to private TableRow.LayoutParams buttonparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(); and now im back in business. Please write an answer so i can give you credit.

Comment: @mpeerman I have posted answer...

Comment: @mpeerman This is what I have used in my answer as well TableRow.LayoutParams blp = new TableRow.LayoutParams();

Comment: Yes but his original comment was posted before your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Layout params you've used for the TableRow should be of TableRow.LayoutParams,
 try

```
TableRow.LayoutParams buttonparams = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example as a reference.

```
LinearLayout imageslayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.imageslayout);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                Button im = new Button(getApplicationContext());

                TableRow.LayoutParams blp = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
                blp.rightMargin = 20;
                blp.width=170;
                blp.height=140;  
                im.setLayoutParams(blp); 


                imageslayout.addView(im); 
                im.setOnClickListener(this);

            }
```

Comment: I dont see any difference between that and mine other than im using a table layout and rows and buttons

Comment: Seriously! @mpeerman says he searched all night and you just throw a bit of code in his direction, hoping for some reputation points. Man.

Comment: My thought is not about reputation point but to give a simple working example.I know he searched all night but a simple example might help him or others as well.

Answer (score 0):

set button params through constructor like buttonParams = new LayoutParams(height,width) instead of setting through buttonParams.height  = height and so. difference is that assignment do not call invalidate, hence dimen will be zero.